# Errors LNK 2019 and LNK2028 for one function in a class, other works fine

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I normally work in c# and am out of my wits for this one . I used [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx) to create a Dynamic Link Library.

I have defined two methods as shown below

**DeveloperConsoleManager.h**

```
#pragma once  
#include "atlstr.h"

#ifdef DEVCONSOLEMANAGER_EXPORTS  
    #define DEVCONSOLEMANAGER_API __declspec(dllexport)   
#else  
    #define DEVCONSOLEMANAGER_API __declspec(dllimport)   
#endif  

namespace DeveloperConsoleManager  
{      
    class DeveloperConsoleLogic  
    {  
        public:  
            // Returns a + b  
            static DEVCONSOLEMANAGER_API double Add(double a, double b);  
            static DEVCONSOLEMANAGER_API bool CheckforValidFile(CString fileName);
    };  
}
```

**DeveloperConsoleManager.cpp**

```
// DeveloperConsoleManager.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "DeveloperConsoleManager.h"

namespace DeveloperConsoleManager  
{
    double DeveloperConsoleLogic::Add(double a, double b)  
    {  
        return a + b;  
    }  


    bool DeveloperConsoleLogic :: CheckforValidFile(CString fileName)
    {       
        return false;
    }
}
```

I use these methods in a .cpp file in a different project (type: Application (.exe)). When I Build the solution, there are following linker errors

> Warning    1   warning C4273: 'DeveloperConsoleManager::DeveloperConsoleLogic::Add' : inconsistent dll linkage e:\md_69\developerconsolemanager\developerconsolemanager.cpp    10
>
> Warning    2   warning C4273: 'DeveloperConsoleManager::DeveloperConsoleLogic::CheckforValidFile' : inconsistent dll linkage   e:\md_69\developerconsolemanager\developerconsolemanager.cpp    16
>
> Error  3   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A0004F1) "public: static bool __cdecl DeveloperConsoleManager::DeveloperConsoleLogic::CheckforValidFile(class ATL::CStringT > >)" (?CheckforValidFile@DeveloperConsoleLogic@DeveloperConsoleManager@@$$FSA_NV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CSaSsiConsoleUi::UploadSsiCheck(void)" (?UploadSsiCheck@CSaSsiConsoleUi@@$$FQAEXXZ)   E:\MD_69\DeveloperConsoleUI\SaSsiConsoleUI.obj
>
> Error  4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl DeveloperConsoleManager::DeveloperConsoleLogic::CheckforValidFile(class ATL::CStringT > >)" (?CheckforValidFile@DeveloperConsoleLogic@DeveloperConsoleManager@@$$FSA_NV?$CStringT@_WV?$StrTraitMFC_DLL@_WV?$ChTraitsCRT@_W@ATL@@@@@ATL@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CSaSsiConsoleUi::UploadSsiCheck(void)" (?UploadSsiCheck@CSaSsiConsoleUi@@$$FQAEXXZ)    E:\MD_69\DeveloperConsoleUI\SaSsiConsoleUI.obj
>
> Error  5   error LNK1120: 2 unresolved externals   E:\MD_69\Debug\DeveloperConsoleUi.exe

There is no linker error for the "Add" method.

I have already included "DeveloperConsoleManager.lib" in Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies. Please help me find out what exactly am I doing wrong.
I would be glad to add any additional information needed.

Comment: _'DeveloperConsoleManager::DeveloperConsoleLogic::Add' : inconsistent dll linkage_

Comment: @manni66 I'm sorry but could you please elaborate

Comment: Fix that. Maybe it fixes the rest.

Comment: @manni66 The warnings were due to incorrect preprocessor definition, in project properties . Resolved that, however the Linker errors are still there

Comment: `CString` is a macro that may expand to many different things depending on project settings. I suspect the two modules are built with different settings, and disagree on the meaning of `CString`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik , That was it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Igor Tandetnik and the awesome thing that is internet, I figured it out. I am adding it as an answer so that some one else might benefit.

The problem was with CString. The project in which the function was defined was a dynamic link library (dll) and the call was being made from an MFC application. Now, the issue was that, MFC uses  for CString while the non-MFC dll uses .

CString in  is defined as:

```
typedef ATL::CStringT< TCHAR, StrTraitMFC_DLL< TCHAR > > CString;
```

while in  is defined as:

```
typedef CStringT< TCHAR, StrTraitATL< TCHAR > > CString;
```

This, as you can clearly see is different. The workaround I used was [using CAtlString instead of CString](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4072/Linker-Errors-CString-ATL-MFC-and-YOU) . However, please feel free to suggest any better way if you come across.